# Using pass on an usb

Tags: password, password-store

I really like the way [pass](https://www.passwordstore.org/) stores passwords but i want to know if i can use it to save from another location that isnt ~/.password-store (lets say a usb).

Answer (score 1):

Set the environment variable `PASSWORD_STORE_DIR` to the location you want and just use `pass` normally.

Answer (score 0):

You could always symlink it

`ln /mnt/usb/file.pass ~/.password-store`

Comment: You left out a `-s`, or does `ln` handle cross-filesystem links differently and I didn't know it?